# TYPO3 Form Framework: personalized email

Tags: email, typo3

Is it possible to send a personalized email with the extension form?

For example: Hello Paul ...

where "Paul" is a value from a form field. How can I insert the value in the email template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution

1. Insert {title} in the email template. The values are defined in the form.yaml in the finisher section.
2. Insert {form.request.arguments.field-identifier} in the email template